# List view values cause an error

Tags: android, database

I have a database in one activity that I want to open in another activity, also in this activity I wish to create a List View:

my code as follows

```
messagedb=context.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);
                    messagedb.execSQL(
                            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab( " +
            " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ," +
            " nickname varchar,sender INT(13),body varchar)");


                    messagedb.execSQL("INSERT INTO tab VALUES('"+nickname+"','"+sender+"','"+sb+"')");
                    messagedb.close();
                    mydb.close();
```

when i am inserting values it says your database having 4 columns but you have ente 3 column values.............how can i add _id automatically from table......

my listView activity as below

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

SQLiteDatabase messagedb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_list);



    messagedb=ListView.this.openOrCreateDatabase("message",0, null);
    messagedb.execSQL(
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tab(" +
            " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            " nickname varchar,sender INT(13),body varchar)");



    Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select _id, nickname, body from tab", null);
    String[] from = new String[] { "nickname", "body" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.sender_entry, R.id.body_entry};

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.my_list_entry, cur, from, to);

    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    cur.close();

    messagedb.close();


}

protected void onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    String nickName = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sender_entry)).getText().toString();

    String body = ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.body_entry)).getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ListView.this,MessageViewPage.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putString("nick", nickName);
    b.putString("body", body);

    intent.putExtras(b);

    startActivity(intent);

    finish();





}

}
```

Comment: What's your problem? What's your error? What's the meaning of life?!

Comment: when i am inserting values it says your database having 4 columns but you have enter 3 column values....... in first lines of codes not listView....i realize that it says id is missing...na? But i dont know how can i add id automatically in my table....suggest me how can i add id to the table?

Comment: how can i add a null value in a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
" _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,"
```

Should be this if you want the DB to automatically take care of the primary key for you:

```
" _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
```

Otherwise you need to manually add the "_id" when you do an insert.

Using `autoincrement` is by far the easier solution.

Then if you want all data from the record, simply do this:

```
Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select * from tab", null);
```

If you only want specific bits, only call for them (but remember when using most Android widgets, you **must** have `_id` in the cursor, even if you don't display it).  So if you just wanted the nickname, your query might look like this:

```
Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select _id, nickname from tab", null);
```

You also should only have code to create the table in one place.  Having it in two places is just bad.  It looks like what is happening now is you changed one but not the other, and the one you didn't change is getting called first, creating the table without your change then when the second one gets called, the table alre4ady exists so it doesn't make your changes.  At the least you need to change both table creation statements to be the same.  the better solution is to get rid of one of them.

You should also use ContentValues to do your inserts...

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
initialValues.put("nickname", nickname);
initialValues.put("sender", sender);
initialValues.put("body", sb);
messagedb.insertWithOnConflict(tab, null, initialValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

Oh, you'll have problems if you close the cursor while your list is still active.  Get rid of the `cur.close()` call and instead all `startManagingCursor(cur);` right after you get the cursor. That way the system will manage the cursor for you.

Comment: but in my second activity define id as null...so how can i change   ` Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select rowid as _id, nickname, body from tab", null);`     this

Comment: You change it as I showed in my answer.  The "rowid as _id" is where it falls apart, you don't have a column called "rowid", so it comes back null.  You should use `Cursor cur = messagedb.rawQuery("select _id, nickname, body from tab", null);` once you have re-created your database using `autoincrement`.

Comment: in my database having values but i cant get that values using your code

Comment: You have to re-create your database and re-populate it because you are changing the schema (assuming you are changing to use `autoincrement`).  The easiest way is to uninstall your app and then re-install it.

Comment: Try using ContentValues (I added an example to my answer).

Comment: Sorry, I pulled that from an insert method in one of my apps.  Get rid of `return` and change `mDb` to `messagedb`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your ID to autoincrement:
ID integer primary key autoincrement
I also suggest to use ContentValues to insert values into DB using method sqlDB.insert(table, nullColumnHack, values). It's easier and less error prone.